# Python "Def" Invalid Syntax

Tags: python

I am kinda new to python and I only been learning it for about a week. I am writing some script and I am using two def statements and it will say Invalid syntax fro the first def of the two defs

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

master = Tk()
def continue():
    answer = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion('Error 408!', 'Something went wrong here. Click terminate to quit the app')
    if answer == 'Yes':
        quit()

dlabel = Label(text='Pick a Button').pack()
master.title('Uselessapp')
master.geometry('200x200')

button = Button(master, text="Play Game", command=continue)
button.pack()

mlabel = Label(text='--------').pack()

def quitapp():
    quit()

button = Button(master, text="Quit", command=quitapp)

button.pack()

mainloop()
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have named your function `continue` which is a reserved word in python

> The following identifiers are used as reserved words, or keywords of the language, and cannot be used as ordinary identifiers.

```
False      class      finally    is         return
None       continue   for        lambda     try
True       def        from       nonlocal   while
and        del        global     not        with
as         elif       if         or         yield
assert     else       import     pass
break      except     in         raise
```

Comment: Thanks and when I was fixing the problem in the code I ran into another problem: (sorry I am new to python)

Comment: import tkinter.messagebox


master = Tk()
def cont():
    answer = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion('Error 408!', 'Something went wrong here. Click terminate to quit the app')
    if answer == 'Yes;
        quit()
    else:






dlabel = Label(text='Pick a Button').pack()
master.title('Uselessapp')
master.geometry('200x200')


button = Button(master, text="Play Game", command=cont)

button.pack()

mlabel = Label(text='--------').pack()

def quitapp():
    quit()

button = Button(master, text="Quit", command=quitapp)

button.pack()

mainloop()

Comment: i get an error that says /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 /Users/imac/PycharmProjects/untitled4/package/Uselessapp.py
  File "/Users/imac/PycharmProjects/untitled4/package/Uselessapp.py", line 10
    if answer == 'Yes;
                     ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Man, are you even trying to debug this ? Anyway... the line where it says `if answer == 'Yes;` should be changed to: `if answer == 'Yes':`

Answer (score 6):

You are using a keyword as a function name which cannot be used as it's reserved by Python.There is an actual keyword called `continue` in Python.Use a different name for your function.One that is not a keyword.